# How to divide a string into parts - Roman numerals

Tags: c++, roman-numerals

I'm trying to divide a string into parts for reading Roman numerals. For example if the user enters

```
"XI"
```

I want the program to be able to understand that I is 1 and X is 10 in order for a data validation like this to work.

```
if(string roman == "X") int roman += 10;
 etc.
```

Comment: Beware assignment `=` versus comparison `==`, and between strings `"X"` and characters `'X'`.  Also, the declaration of '`int roman += 10;`' adds 10 to an indeterminate value - unlikely to be what you intended, plus it hides the declaration of any value being accumulated outside that '`if`' statement.

Comment: It was just a short example so people would get the gist of what I meant :/ But you're right about the assignment operator, a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access an individual character from a string, use square brackets:

```
int num = 0;
char r = roman[0];
if (r == 'X') {
    num += 10;
}
```

The above is by no means a complete example, but should be enough to get you started. This example looks at the first character in the string `roman` (characters are numbered starting at the left with index 0). It checks to see whether the character is `'X'`, and if so, increments the `num` variable by 10.

Answer (score 3):

Function for doing this from a language you don't know, treat as pseudocode:

```
int from_roman_numeral(string val) {
    val = upper_case(val);
    if(val == "N")
        return 0;
    status neg = False;
    if(val[0] == '-') {
        neg = True;
        val = val[1..];
    }
    int out = 0;
    int last = 0;
    int array values = allocate(127);
    values['M'] = 1000;
    values['D'] = 500;
    values['C'] = 100;
    values['L'] = 50;
    values['X'] = 10;
    values['V'] = 5;
    values['I'] = 1;
    int value;
    int next;
    for(int idx = 0, int len = strlen(val); idx < len; idx++) {
        value = values[val[idx]];
        unless(value)
            error("'" + val + "' is not a valid Roman numeral sequence");
        if(idx < len - 1 && (next = values[val[idx + 1]]) && next > value) {
            out += next - value;
            idx++;
        } else {
            out += value;
        }
    }
    return neg ? -out : out;
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding where the '-' character is coming from...  there are no negative signs in roman numerals.

Comment: I support it for my local purposes.  If you don't like it, tear it out.